# MVC FindView Time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-mini-profiler, mvcminiprofiler

I created my first Web App with MVC 4.0 and I just started using mini-profiler to get some basic information. FindView seems to range from 300 to 600ms depending on page, this seems rather high to me but I don't really know what I should be expecting.

Are there basic things I can do to improve the findview performance?

Comment: don't worry about that too much, in debug, views aren't cached, in release mode, they are, so performance hit isn't so bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In release mode views are cached, so you should see those times far lower that what you're seeing now.

Running it in debug mode might give you results similar to what you're finding.